# Как из обычного списка сделать связанный

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, структуры-данных

Пока я решал задачи по Python, я наткнулся на проблему. Нужно было убрать повторяющиеся элементы из связанного списка. Я записывал уникальные элементы в обычный список, и теперь его нужно перевести в связанный.

Кто-нибудь, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать в Python 3?

Задача:  https://stepik.org/lesson/299046/step/3?unit=280885

Вам дан односвязный отсортированный список. Избавьтесь от дупликатов так, чтобы в списке содержались только уникальные элементы.

Sample Input:

1->4->6->7->9->9->10->11->14->14

Sample Output:

1->4->6->7->9->10->11->14

Код:

```py
# Определение односвязного списка.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution:
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        a = []
        i = 0
        while head:
            for r in a:
                if head.val == r:
                    remove_list_item_by_id(i)
            
            a.append(str(head.val))
            head = head.next
            i +=1
        return a
```

Задача принимает только связанный список (следует из ошибки)

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Первый сайт в Яндексе при запросе "python преобразование списка в связный список": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553576/converting-a-list-to-a-linked-list

Comment: @Глеб поправил, спасибо за пояснение!

Comment: "связанный" -> "связный"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто. Что-то такое, если на входе отсортированный связный список, не надо усложнять задачу без нужды:

```py
class Solution:
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        while head:
            while head.next and head.val == head.next.val:
                head.next = head.next.next
            head = head.next
```

То есть просто выкидываем повторяющиеся элементы, меняя ссылку с текущего элемента так, чтобы пропустить следующий.

Comment: Почему то код возвращает "" когда подаётся 1->4->6->7->9->9->10->11->14->14

Comment: Ну сами подумайте - если в задании **и верните указатель на начало**, значит надо запомнить начало, и вернуть его return

Comment: Спасибо! Я просто с односвязными списками знаком буквально несколько часов

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что эта учебная задача рассчитана на то, что вы работаете только с данным списком, не используя другие структуры данных.

Поэтому не плодите сущности без необходимости. Запомните head, и пройдите по списку, для каждого элемента p делая ещё один прогон с начала до p, и если нашли такое же значение, то удаляйте p.

---

Условие я на сайте посмотреть не могу (его вообще-то принято в точности приводить в вопросе), но раз говорят, что там список сортированный, то всё еще проще - нужно сравнивать значение текущего узла (если он не конечный) со значением следующего, и если совпадают - обновлять next на next.next

Собственно, в ответе CrazyElf код уже есть.

Comment: @rotabor Я на сайт степика не смог зайти, поэтому оперировал только теми данными, что описал автор.